# doctest skips functions with assert

Tags: python-3.x, doctest

I added a unit test for a trivial function using `doctest` - and it works.
Then if I add `assert True` as the first line of that function the unit test is not picked by the `doctest.testmod` anymore. Why is that and how can I use `assert` with `doctest`?